# Changing ui language at runtime

Tags: c#, resources, uwp, culture

I'm trying to change the ui language of my UWP app dynamically. 
Everything works fine except for the page containing the language combobox itself.

I have to pick a language from the combobox twice to see the page change to another language, why do i have to do this twice?

```
private void comboUILanguages_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
        ResourceController.ChangeUILanguage((string)((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem);

        //for now, use a simple condition to determine wheter the page should be refreshed immediatly
        if (true)
        {
            MainPage.Current.RefreshMenu();
            Reload(currentGroup);
        }
}

private bool Reload(object param = null)
{
        var type = Frame.CurrentSourcePageType;

        try
        {
            return Frame.Navigate(type, param);
        }
        finally
        {
            Frame.BackStack.Remove(Frame.BackStack.Last());
        }
}
```

My ResourceController:

```
class ResourceController
{
    private static ResourceLoader resourceLoader = ResourceLoader.GetForViewIndependentUse();

    public static string GetTranslation(string resource)
    {
        return resourceLoader.GetString(resource);
    }

    public static void ChangeUILanguage(string language)
    {
        Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = language;
        Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse().Reset();
    }

    public static string GetCurrentUILanguage()
    {
        return CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName; 
    }
}
```

Comment: When you initialize your page, what entry is selected in the `ComboBox`? Maybe you have an issue with the reloading and select the "old" language after the first reload. Or maybe this needs some time (try to sleep 100ms). I don't think it's the latter but you can try.

Comment: It's solved by putting the reset in the constructor. But i have no idea why though. If it needed some time they would probably create an async method to set PrimaryLanguageOverride